# Two-way repeated measures anova using a "categoryish" independent variable?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, spss, two-way

I am trying to run a two-way repeated measures anova in spss but i think my data needs restructuring. I have run anova's in spss before so i am familiar with process. The problem is that when i have previously run a two-way repeated measures anova it has been using two sets of numerical values (times). In this case i am trying to look for significance between a set of numerical data (times) against what is effectively a categorical variable (as seen in be data outlining below). The version order is a variable (column) and so it appears when i'm defining the anova test within spss.

My issue is that when i define the subject factors and levels within spss:

[image]

On the next screen i have to enter all the variables.

[image]

But i only have four variables to use.

[image]

As you can see from the basic outline of my data at the bottom, the version order is in one variable. I don't have a variable for each order sequence.

I am trying to run the anova to see the effect that the version order had on the total time for each version. I also plan to run an anova to look at the effect the version order had on version performance in each task.

I have 'long' and 'wide' versions of my data

Long:

[image]

Wide:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found the solution, a Mixed ANOVA :)

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? Why is a mixed ANOVA the solution?